# Changeing an SVG from 238 to 266 and now I'm stuck

Tags: svg

This was originally 238, I want to change it to 266, and now I'm stuck.

I've done this before, but I forgot how to do it.

I know 7 goes into 266 38 times. See, I forgot how to do all this math, how you're supposed to calculate it.

I'm confused now.

It should all fit evenly I think, or does it not?

```html
 <svg width="266" height="266" viewBox="0 0 266 266">
          <rect x="0" y="0" width="266" height="266" fill="blue" />
          <rect x="7" y="7" width="224" height="224" fill="black" />
          <rect x="14" y="14" width="210" height="210" fill="red" />
          <rect x="21" y="21" width="196" height="196" fill="black" />
          <rect x="28" y="28" width="182" height="182" fill="yellow" />
          <rect x="35" y="35" width="168" height="168" fill="black" />
          <rect x="42" y="42" width="154" height="154" fill="orange" />
          <rect x="49" y="49" width="140" height="140" fill="black" />
          <rect x="56" y="56" width="126" height="126" fill="lime" />
          <rect x="63" y="63" width="112" height="112" fill="black" />
          <rect x="70" y="70" width="98" height="98" fill="teal" />
          <rect x="77" y="77" width="84" height="84" fill="black" />
          <rect x="84" y="84" width="70" height="70" fill="silver" />
          <rect x="91" y="91" width="56" height="56" fill="black" />
          <rect x="98" y="98" width="42" height="42" fill="#1155cc" />
          <rect x="105" y="105" width="28" height="28" fill="black" />
          <rect x="112" y="112" width="14" height="14" fill="gold" />
        </svg>
```

Comment: I assume by 238 to 266, you mean the width and height?  You haven't posted the original SVG, so we don't know what it is supposed to look like.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the original looked like this:

```html
<svg width="238" height="238" viewBox="0 0 238 238">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="238" height="238" fill="blue" />
  <rect x="7" y="7" width="224" height="224" fill="black" />
  <rect x="14" y="14" width="210" height="210" fill="red" />
  <rect x="21" y="21" width="196" height="196" fill="black" />
  <rect x="28" y="28" width="182" height="182" fill="yellow" />
  <rect x="35" y="35" width="168" height="168" fill="black" />
  <rect x="42" y="42" width="154" height="154" fill="orange" />
  <rect x="49" y="49" width="140" height="140" fill="black" />
  <rect x="56" y="56" width="126" height="126" fill="lime" />
  <rect x="63" y="63" width="112" height="112" fill="black" />
  <rect x="70" y="70" width="98" height="98" fill="teal" />
  <rect x="77" y="77" width="84" height="84" fill="black" />
  <rect x="84" y="84" width="70" height="70" fill="silver" />
  <rect x="91" y="91" width="56" height="56" fill="black" />
  <rect x="98" y="98" width="42" height="42" fill="#1155cc" />
  <rect x="105" y="105" width="28" height="28" fill="black" />
  <rect x="112" y="112" width="14" height="14" fill="gold" />
</svg>
```

Then all you have to do to scale it up to 266x266 is to update the `width` and `height` attributes.

```
<svg width="266" height="266" viewBox="0 0 238 238">
```

Because the SVG has a `viewBox`, the browser will scale the contents automatically for you.

```html
<svg width="266" height="266" viewBox="0 0 238 238">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="238" height="238" fill="blue" />
  <rect x="7" y="7" width="224" height="224" fill="black" />
  <rect x="14" y="14" width="210" height="210" fill="red" />
  <rect x="21" y="21" width="196" height="196" fill="black" />
  <rect x="28" y="28" width="182" height="182" fill="yellow" />
  <rect x="35" y="35" width="168" height="168" fill="black" />
  <rect x="42" y="42" width="154" height="154" fill="orange" />
  <rect x="49" y="49" width="140" height="140" fill="black" />
  <rect x="56" y="56" width="126" height="126" fill="lime" />
  <rect x="63" y="63" width="112" height="112" fill="black" />
  <rect x="70" y="70" width="98" height="98" fill="teal" />
  <rect x="77" y="77" width="84" height="84" fill="black" />
  <rect x="84" y="84" width="70" height="70" fill="silver" />
  <rect x="91" y="91" width="56" height="56" fill="black" />
  <rect x="98" y="98" width="42" height="42" fill="#1155cc" />
  <rect x="105" y="105" width="28" height="28" fill="black" />
  <rect x="112" y="112" width="14" height="14" fill="gold" />
</svg>
```

Comment: If I wanted to do 266 in the viewBox also, what numbers would I change in the middle part? Is that possible to do?

Comment: Assuming you wanted to keep the same number of coloured squares, you'd need to update all the `x`, `y`, `width` and `height` attributes.  You would need to multiple all the `width` and `height` values by (266/238) and set all the `x` and `y` attributes to ((266 - width) / 2).

Comment: Keeping the same number of squares isn't important, just that they're 7" wide each.

Comment: Well then the `x` and `y` would step up by 7 each time as they do now.  The `width` and `height` start at 266 and step down by 14 each time.